# Relationships not working after setTable() in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

Consider without using relation first,

```
    DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
    $oPost = new Post();
    $oPost->setTable('posts_two');
    $aPost = $oPost->get();
    $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
    dd($queries);
```

This results the following query

> select * from `posts_two`

Now , Consider the case with the relation,

```
    DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
    $oPost = new Post();
    $oPost->setTable('posts_two');
    $aPost = $oPost->with('comments')->get();

    $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
    dd($queries);
```

This results the following query

> select * from `posts`

The problem is , Whenever I use `with()`, It is taking default table (posts) instead of the table name which i set via `setTable` (posts_two)

I could not identify why this happens ? Advance thanks for any kind of help. :)

Comment: why dont you use Post::with(['comments'])->get(); ?

Comment: @sandy I have to use setTable first. Then am using with()

Comment: What if refresh instance before relationship ?  $oPost->setTable('posts_two'); $oPost->refresh(); $aPost = $oPost->with('comments')->get();

Comment: @Casper No use. Same response.Any idea?

Comment: Instead of setTable can you try $oPost->bind('connection', 'posts_two');

Comment: @Casper . Yea.,I tried that also by using a trait. But no use. It is still taking default table instead of posts_two

Comment: with() is static function that uses brand new instance so always you get Post instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get()` is [non static](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php) method beacuse of that you received,

> select * from posts_two

However `with()` is [static](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php) method. Static method uses brand new instance so they create new instance that will have default **table property**. Therefore you received,

> select * from posts

According to my understanding you cannot use static method here therefore I think you have to fetch `posts_two` data first and after that you have to fetch `comments` using `posts_two` data and bind togehter.